# Terminate a Spring Boot application that uses Kafka-Streams and MongoDB

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-data-mongodb, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have a Spring Boot application that uses Kafka-Streams. In details, there is a stream that filters the messages it receives using the results of a query performed in MongoDB. The code is something similar to the following.

```
final KStream<String, String> stream =
    kStreamBuilder.stream(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String(), inputTopic)
                  .filter((s, message) -> service.hasSomeProperty(message))
                  .to(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String(), outpuTopic);
```

The method `service.hasSomeProperty(message)` calls a Mongo repository that performs a query on a dedicated collection.

If there are some problems during the communication with Mongo, the exception is intercepted in the thread used by Spring to handle the stream. **The stream stops to work, but the application does not stop properly.**

In detail, the error we are facing is the following.

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:88)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:494)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:224)
at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.receiveMessage(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:96)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.receiveMessage(DefaultConnectionPool.java:440)
at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.execute(CommandProtocol.java:112)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:168)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:289)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:176)
at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:216)
at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:207)
at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:113)
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:516)
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:510)
at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:435)
at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:408)
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:510)
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:81)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:836)
at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:823)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor.initializeCursor(DBCursor.java:870)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:142)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor.one(DBCursor.java:679)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:833)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:796)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:743)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$FindOneCallback.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:2179)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$FindOneCallback.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:2163)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1907)
... 31 more
```

**All I want to know is** how I can configure the Spring Boot application to stop in case of communication errors with Mongo inside a Kafka stream filter.

I know that this is not the best possible approach, but I cannot refactor too much the code to use a `GlobalKTable` instead of a Mongo collection.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i did in one of my applications, inside the Spring Component that is managing the KafkaStreams instance and implementing InitializingBean and DisposableBean interfaces:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;

private KafkaStreams streams;

@Override
public void destroy() throws Exception {
    if(streams.state().isRunning())
        streams.close();
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

    ... // streams setup

    streams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((Thread thread, Throwable throwable) -> {
        LOG.error("Unexpected error in stream processing for thread: " + thread, throwable);
        closeApp();
    });

    ... // streams start

}

private void closeApp() {
    ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) appContext).close();
}
```

Up to now this worked fine for me. You could decide to stop your application only on exceptions raised by Mongo connections.

Comment: Thanks, Enrico. It's a pleasure to find you here. I will give a try to your solution and I will let you know.